# How to create a table using report lab that can change the number of rows dynamically

Tags: python-2.7, reportlab

I am creating a PDF that has a table in it except the table rows will differ from PDF to PDF

```
    table = Table(data, colWidths=[3.05 * cm, 4.5 * cm, 4 * cm,3* cm, 3 * cm])
    table.setStyle(TableStyle([
                   ('INNERGRID', (0,0), (-1,-1), 0.25, black),
                   ('BOX', (0,0), (-1,-1), 0.25, black),
                   ]))
    table.wrapOn(self.pdf, self.width_table, self.height_table)
    table.drawOn(self.pdf, *self.coord(1.0, 18.6,cm))
```

That is what I am using to create the table with now.

Thanks,

Comment: I don't understand. What is your question?

Comment: I was looking for a function in reportlab that would create a table given row paramater but I just used a loop and that worked.

Answer (score 3):

It's a central question for anyone starting out.

Below is a complete workable code to start build from. The answer is, as you wrote yourself in the comment, is to loop. Problems, though, that anyone later will discover is how you deal with multi-page tables and design of those tables. There are various solutions worth looking into.

```
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter
from reportlab.lib import colors
from reportlab.platypus import Frame, PageTemplate, KeepInFrame
from reportlab.lib.units import cm
from reportlab.platypus import (Table, TableStyle, BaseDocTemplate)

########################################################################

def create_pdf():
    """
    Create a pdf
    """

    # Create a frame
    text_frame = Frame(
        x1=3.00 * cm,  # From left
        y1=1.5 * cm,  # From bottom
        height=19.60 * cm,
        width=15.90 * cm,
        leftPadding=0 * cm,
        bottomPadding=0 * cm,
        rightPadding=0 * cm,
        topPadding=0 * cm,
        showBoundary=1,
        id='text_frame')

    # Create a table
    test_table = []
    data = []
    for i in range(11, 1, -1):
        column1data = f'Column_1 on row {i}'
        column2data = f'Column_2 on row {i}'
        data.append([column1data, column2data])

    data_table = Table(data, 15.90 * cm / 2)
    data_table.setStyle(TableStyle([
        # Title
        ('LEFTPADDING', (0, 0), (1, 0), 0),
        ('RIGHTPADDING', (0, 0), (1, 0), 0),
        ('VALIGN', (0, 0), (1, 0), 'TOP'),
        ('ALIGN', (0, 0), (1, 0), 'CENTRE'),
        # DataTable
        ('ALIGN', (0, 1), (1, -1), 'CENTRE'),
        ('SIZE', (0, 1), (-1, -1), 7),
        ('LEADING', (0, 1), (-1, -1), 8.4),
        ('VALIGN', (0, 1), (-1, -1), 'MIDDLE'),
        ('TOPPADDING', (0, 1), (-1, -1), 2.6),
        ('BOTTOMPADDING', (0, 1), (-1, -1), 2.6),
        ('LINEBELOW', (0, 1), (-1, -1), 0.3, colors.gray),
    ]))

    test_table.append(data_table)
    test_table = KeepInFrame(0, 0, test_table, mode='overflow')

    # Building the story
    story = [test_table] # adding test_table table (alternative, story.add(test_table))

    # Establish a document
    doc = BaseDocTemplate("Example_output.pdf", pagesize=letter)

    # Creating a page template
    frontpage = PageTemplate(id='FrontPage',
                             frames=[text_frame]
                             )
    # Adding the story to the template and template to the document
    doc.addPageTemplates(frontpage)

    # Building doc
    doc.build(story)


# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
if __name__ == "__main__":
    create_pdf() # Printing the pdf
```